# Is there a way to force a Random Forest Regressor to not fit an intercept?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

Is there a way to fit an sklearn Random Forest Regressor such that an all 0 input will give me a 0 prediction? For linear models, I know I can simply pass in a `fit_intercept=False` argument upon initialization, and I want to replicate this for the random forest.

Does it make sense for a tree-based model to achieve what I'm trying to do? If so, how do I implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

---

Long answer:

Tree-based models are very different animals from linear ones; the notion of intercept does not even exist in trees.

To get some intuition on why is so, let's adapt the simple example from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-tree-regression-py) (one decision tree with a single input feature):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor, plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a random dataset
rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
X = np.sort(5 * rng.rand(80, 1), axis=0)
y = np.sin(X).ravel()
y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - rng.rand(16))

# Fit regression model
regr = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2)
regr.fit(X, y)

# Predict
X_test = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)[:, np.newaxis]
y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)

# Plot the results
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X, y, s=20, edgecolor="black",
            c="darkorange", label="data")
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color="cornflowerblue",
         label="max_depth=2", linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel("data")
plt.ylabel("target")
plt.title("Decision Tree Regression")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Roughly speaking, decision trees attempt to approximate the data *locally*, hence any global attempt (such as an intercept line) does not exist in their universe.

What a regression tree actually returns as output is the *mean value* of the dependent variable `y` of the training samples that end up in the respective terminal nodes (leaves) during fitting. To see this, let's plot the tree we have just fitted above:

```
plt.figure()
plot_tree(regr, filled=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Traversing the tree in this very simple toy example, you should be able to convince yourself that the prediction for `X=0` is `0.052` (left arrows are the `True` condition of the nodes). Let's verify this:

```
regr.predict(np.array([0]).reshape(1,-1))
# array([0.05236068])
```

I illustrated the above with a very simple decision tree to give you an idea of why the notion of an intercept does not exist here; the conclusion that this is also the case with any model that is actually based upon and consists of decision trees (like the Random Forest) should be straightforward.

Comment: Than you so much for the clear, detailed explanation. Much appreciated!